# Android Tabactivity with different apk's

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity

i found that when using android TabActivity to open tabs where each tab is an activity works fines. (used the android example HelloTabWidget)

But when i try activating one of the tabs as an activity from a different apk, it causes a crash.

do you know if it even possible, and if so what are the requirements for that to succeed?

thank for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot embed activities from another application in your `TabActivity`.

Also note that embedding activities in a TabActivity has been deprecated in general, so you should start considering other strategies, such as using fragments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so with fragments is it possible to do what I asked?